# JavaScript Sort to clear a sort that has already been made

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I am trying to create my own sort function for a table, I'm not allowed to use a plugin to this as part of my University Coursework.

Now I've got some JavaScript mark up here which will sort the table nicely:

```
var newDirection = 1;
if ($(this).is('.sorted-asc')) {
    newDirection = -1;
}

var rows = $table.find('tbody > tr').get();
$.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    row.sortKey =
        findSortKey($(row).children('td').eq(column));
});

rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.sortKey < b.sortKey) return -newDirection;
    if (a.sortKey > b.sortKey) return newDirection;
    return 0;
});
```

The sortkey variables are just whether it is sorted by Alpha or Numeric.

Here I will change the rows in the table to be in the correct order:

```
$.each(rows, function (index, row) {
    $table.children('tbody').append(row);
    row.sortKey = null;
});
```

Now what I would love to work out, is there a way in which I can reverse the sort? I don't mean `.reverse()` which will reverse the order of the table rows but actually clear the sort and put the values back to the way they were.

I'd like to make it so the table order that was default comes back.

**EDIT:**
This was my attempt at it:
I declared a previous variable just after I declared the rows variable:

```
var previous = $table.find('tbody > tr').get();
```

And then tried to reorder it in a similar way to how I set it:

```
$table.siblings('a.reset').click(function () {
    $.each(previous, function (index, row) {
        $table.children('tbody').append(row);
    });
});
```

Comment: This is where sample input and expected output will help.

Comment: Well let's say I have three items "C", "Z", "A". If I clicked to sort the table via alpha then the order of my table rows would be "A", "C", "Z". This works without any problems. Now how can I clear the sort so that it goes back to "C", "Z", "A"?

Comment: Once the collection is sorted, you cannot revert it. You might have to store the index of the individual rows before sorting.

Comment: Well this is where I adjust it:
$.each(rows, function (index, row) {
                                    $table.children('tbody').append(row);
                                    row.sortKey = null;
                                });

Comment: The only way you could get the original sequence is if you make a copy of the object before you use it.  Do you just want it so it mixes them back up, not caring about the original way it was organized? @Matthew

Comment: Loop over all rows once before you sort, and assign their current index to a _custom data attribute_ of the element. Then, if you want to restore the original order again, simply sort them by the value of that custom data attribute.

Comment: Is it possible to do it in a similar way to the edit I just made where I get the previous order before it's ever changed? What I've written changes the order but not in the way I had anticipated.

Comment: To sort array A make 1:1 array S = [0, 1, 2, 3 ...] and sort this using the comparison function int comp(i,j){ return A[S[i]] - A[S[j];}

Comment: My edit actually works, I didn't realise that as I was using a pagination feature that it was clashing with it. In order to fix it I had to ensure that the table repaginates at the same time.